# Using numpy.rate, on numpy array returns nan's unexpectedly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using np.rate function to calculate simple growth rates. I'm trying to use vector operations. This works:

```
b = np.arange(1,10)
np.rate(1,0,-b[:-1],b[1:])
```

This returns:
array([ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ,  0.2       ,
        0.16666667,  0.14285714,  0.125     ])

However, this doesn't work as I'm expecting:

```
b = np.arange(10)
np.rate(1,0,-b[:-1],b[1:])
```

Returns:
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])

Any thoughts to best remedy this? I'm assuming the 0 in the first index position is giving the np.rate function some problems but I'm not sure what the best way to correct this is. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I get this error: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide`. So probably this is the reason.

Comment: If my answer isn't sufficient, can you tell me what more you'd like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second case has a zero in `b`.

np.rate can't handle a 0 value there.

As well as I can understand from the (brief) documentation of np.rate, you're asking it to find what interest rate is needed to turn 0 into 1 in a single pay period.  This is a challenging problem you're asking it to solve.

To fix it, you simply need to not have a 0 there.

Comment: Hi Joel. Thanks for your answer. It's understood that getting an answer to the question you pose is not feasible. But what is surprising to me is the rate function's response. Instead of placing a nan for that particular element, every element in the vector is nan. It's an all-or-nothing approach that I didn't expect. I can create my own function to handle this. Perhaps by changing all zeros to some arbitrary number and then nan-ing it out in the results?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two potential workarounds.

(1) store -b[:-1] and b[1:] in a pandas DataFrame, and use .apply to calculate np.rate for each row. This will be slower than the vectorised approach in your example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as npf # I get a warning telling me to use numpy_financial instead of numpy
b = np.arange(0,10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':-b[:-1],'b':b[1:]})
res = df.apply(lambda x: npf.rate(1,0,x.a,x.b),axis=1)
# [nan,0.9999999999999999, 0.4999999999999999, 0.33333333333333326, 0.24999999999999992, 0.2, 0.1666666666666667, 0.1428571428571427, 0.12499999999999992]
```

(2) Store in a Pandas dataframe, and add a filter for the entries being valid. In your example, nper > 0 but in other cases you would also want to filter for other criteria, such as (pmt * npt) >= pv.

```
valid_df = df.loc[df['a'] !=0] # in real examples add other filtering here.
```

You can then use the vectorised calculation only on these filtered rows.

```
df['result'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['a'] != 0,'result'] = npf.rate(1,0,valid_df.a,valid_df.b)
```